# Is there a common way of exporting Org mode tasks to sqlite?

Tags: org-export

I would like to export tasks from Org file to a middle file in order to convert it later to other back-ends. Should I use CSV format, database format or is there a common parser for this type of tasks?

Comment: There is [`org-db`](https://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2017/01/03/Find-stuff-in-org-mode-anywhere/) that stores headlines in a sqlite database.

Comment: You absolutely answered my question! Why only in comments?